# Does a thread run on the same CPU/core throughout its life?

Tags: windows, multithreading

In Windows on a multiprocessor machine, does a thread change the CPU/core during its lifetime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threads and CPU Affinity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847432/threads-and-cpu-affinity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does a thread change the CPU/core during its lifetime?

It can.  It doesn't necessarily change, but there is nothing preventing the operating system from moving a thread between cores.

The Windows API does provide some control over this via [SetThreadIdealProcessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or  [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if you need to control a thread's operation.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, by default a [thread can be scheduled on any available core](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can set the thread affinity if you want to restrict a thread to a specific core or cores.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This doesn't answer the question though. A thread may run on any processor, but can it change processor during its lifetime.

Comment: I think you are missing that the scheduler runs continuously, not just at thread creation.

Comment: I see now... ignore my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the thread has a long lifetime with many blocking calls, eg. a pool thread or app-lifetime thread, it is almost certain to run on many different cores - when it becomes ready, the OS will dispatch it onto a free core if there is one available, or may preempt another thread of lower priority running on some core to allow the newly ready thread to run.

Even if the thread has only a short lifetime and is CPU-intensive, there is no guarantee that it will not be preempted at some stage by a higher-priority thread that becomes ready and, possibly, dispatched later onto another core.

Twiddle with the priorities and thread-affinities if you must.  If you manage to generate any numbers that show an overall performance improvement by doing this, please let us know :)